# Create WPF Setup project in visual studio 2012

Tags: wpf, setup-project

I am working on  a WPF application with the frame work 4.5.

Will the application work on the following  operating systems?
•   Windows XP
•   Windows Vista
•   Windows 7
•   Windows 8

Also  I would like  to know about how to create the setup project. In visual studio 2012 , I noticed that there is no setup project template in 2012.
Please help me.

Thanks
Ranish

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Installer XML toolkit, WIX, to create a setup program. It requires more manual work than the basic setup project in VS 2010, but it is powerful and will do everything you need.

http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Will the 4.5 framework application work on the following operating systems? • Windows XP • Windows Vista • Windows 7 • Windows 8

Comment: 4.5 will not work on Windows XP. But Vista, 7 and 8 will run it fine.